# Formatted JSON fro R dataframe

Tags: r, json, dataframe, jsonlite

I have a data frame like this one.

| date | aid | x_axis | y_axis | z_axis |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-12-02 | 10 | 1.0720000 | 9.462000 | 0.0830000 |
| 2018-12-05 | 4 | -1.9322222 | 5.654278 | 6.7933333 |
| 2018-12-05 | 6 | 0.0380000 | 8.662714 | 3.9418571 |
| 2018-12-08 | 6 | 1.3677143 | 9.199286 | 0.2580000 |

If I transform it with `jsonlite::toJSON()` it gives output something like this one

```
[
  {
    "date": "2018-12-02",
    "aid": 10,
    "x_axis": 1.072,
    "y_axis": 9.462,
    "z_axis": 0.083
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-12-05",
    "aid": 4,
    "x_axis": -1.9322,
    "y_axis": 5.6543,
    "z_axis": 6.7933
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-12-05",
    "aid": 6,
    "x_axis": 0.038,
    "y_axis": 8.6627,
    "z_axis": 3.9419
  }
]
```

But I want to create a JSON file like the following format

```
[
    {
        "date": "2018-11-22",
        "1": {
            "mean": {
                "x_axis": 3.11,
                "y_axis": 3.22,
                "z_axis": 3.33
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "mean": {
                "x_axis": 2.11,
                "y_axis": 2.22,
                "z_axis": 2.33
            }
        }
    }
 ]
```

Here column `aid` is nested under `date` and only the value of the `aid` is reported. And there is an additional text "mean" above the mean value of the axes. Does anyone know how to create a formatted output like the following one?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reshape your data into a `list` with the appropriate structure:

```r
result <- split(df, df$date) |>
  lapply(function(x) {
    split(x[-c(1:2)], x$aid) |> 
      lapply(function(y) list(mean = y))
    }) |>
  jsonlite::toJSON() |>
  jsonlite::prettify()
```

Which gives

```r
result
#> {
#>     "2018-12-02": {
#>         "10": {
#>             "mean": [
#>                 {
#>                     "x_axis": 1.072,
#>                     "y_axis": 9.462,
#>                     "z_axis": 0.083
#>                 }
#>             ]
#>         }
#>     },
#>     "2018-12-05": {
#>         "4": {
#>             "mean": [
#>                 {
#>                     "x_axis": -1.9322,
#>                     "y_axis": 5.6543,
#>                     "z_axis": 6.7933
#>                 }
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         "6": {
#>             "mean": [
#>                 {
#>                     "x_axis": 0.038,
#>                     "y_axis": 8.6627,
#>                     "z_axis": 3.9419
#>                 }
#>             ]
#>         }
#>     },
#>     "2018-12-08": {
#>         "6": {
#>             "mean": [
#>                 {
#>                     "x_axis": 1.3677,
#>                     "y_axis": 9.1993,
#>                     "z_axis": 0.258
#>                 }
#>             ]
#>         }
#>     }
#> }
#>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data taken from question in reproducible format**

```r
df <- structure(list(date = c("2018-12-02", "2018-12-05", "2018-12-05", 
"2018-12-08"), aid = c(10L, 4L, 6L, 6L), x_axis = c(1.072, -1.9322222, 
0.038, 1.3677143), y_axis = c(9.462, 5.654278, 8.662714, 9.199286
), z_axis = c(0.083, 6.7933333, 3.9418571, 0.258)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thanks mate for your reply. But in my desired output there are `[]` only at the beginning and at the end of the document and date is reported as `"date": "2018-11-22"` format. If I add an `lapply` to add `"date"` the whole output changes.